# Can a script using the serial port continue running when I unplug the USB?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I have a differential pressure manometer which I connect through USB on a raspberry pi 3 for data logging which I have completed successfully.

What I want to accomplish, is when I remove the USB, the code would enter a sleep mode until it's connected back on.

I'm sorry if my code is a bit childishly straightforward but I'm a physicist and I don't know a lot about optimizing a code etc. Have I missed something huge here?

```
import serial
import time
import os.path

while True:

        if (os.path.exists('/dev/ttyUSB0') == True):
                print ("USB connected")
                time.sleep(1)
                # setup
                pceport = serial.Serial(port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
                        baudrate = 9600,
                        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                        writeTimeout = 0,
                        timeout = 1)

                # command words
                pceport.write([0x55, 0xaa, 0x01]) # connect to serial port to receive data
                print ("Start reading...")
                time.sleep(1)

                # read from the serial port
                while (pceport.isOpen() == True):
                        if (pceport.isOpen() == True):
                                pceport.read(5) # 2 ID bytes, Sign, Voltage and Unit skipped
                        else:
                                pceport.close()
                        if (pceport.isOpen() == True):
                                data = pceport.read(5) # Data bytes (5)
                        else:
                                pceport.close()
                        if (pceport.isOpen() == True):
                                pceport.read(1) # Checkcode byte skipped
                        else:
                                pceport.close()

                        print (data.decode('utf-8'), "mbar")

        else:
                print ("USB disconnected")
                time.sleep(2)
                print ("Trying to reconnect...")
                time.sleep(8)
```

Pi's terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 pcetest.py
USB connected
Start reading...
0.182 mbar
0.139 mbar
0.185 mbar
0.245 mbar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 490, in read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pcetest.py", line 26, in <module>
    pceport.read(5) # 2 ID bytes, Sign, Voltage and Unit skipped
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 497, in read
    raise SerialException('read failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

This is the error when I unplug the USB. I would expect it to exit the reading loop, go back at the top and enter the USB disconnected loop, but that's not the case.

It works perfectly fine the other way around, when it's unplugged and I plug it in:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 pcetest.py
USB disconnected
Trying to reconnect...
USB connected
Start reading...
0.260 mbar
0.228 mbar
0.242 mbar
0.230 mbar
```

Sorry for the long post, I appreciate any comment

Comment: Long post, short comment ;) You need [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and should use [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: My god I cant believe it was that simple! Had no clue a try statement even existed, thank you so much!!!!